# TableController and "other" entities

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I have a User and UserItem entities. Interaction with User entities happens through TableController derived controller and for UserItem through TableController derive controller. This is a back end to a mobile app with sync functionality enabled.

For some updates to User entity, I need to make updates to UserItem(s) and associate them with the User being updated.  As a result, I cannot make these updates on the client because UserItem(s) in question do not yet belong to the User and thus have not be loaded.  The only solution to this is to update the User, update affected UserItem(s) and then force the client to reload.

The question I have is how to update UserItem from within User TableController?

One way which works is to call a stored proc which takes care of manipulating other entities but I am concerned about not setting version string correctly.  Another way would be to instantiate UseritemController from UserController and update UserItem(s) that way - but I am running into issues with instantiation.

Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at chapter 3 of the ZUMO Book: http://aka.ms/zumobook

Short version - the SQL database maintains the version string.  You can use Entity Framework to update the UserItem using the standard EF semantics.